# Get php out of body

Tags: php, html

I've read and heard it is really sensible to separate your PHP and HTML tags as much as possible. Now my question is how should I do that? I couldn't really find the answer so I decided to ask you.
I was thinking about to use the POST function.

Check out my code:

```
<div class="aftelklok rondenSB">
    <a href="?page=agenda">
    <?php 
    // countdown function
    // parameters: (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds)
    countdown(2013,2,24,18,0,0);
    function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $seconds)
    {
        // make a unix timestamp for the given date
        $the_countdown_date = mktime($hour, $minute, $seconds, $month, $day, $year, -1);

        // get current unix timestamp
        $today = time();

        $difference = $the_countdown_date - $today;
        if ($difference < 0) $difference = 0;

        $days_left = floor($difference/60/60/24);
        $hours_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24)/60/60);
        $minutes_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60)/60);
        $seconds_left = floor($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60 - $minutes_left*60);
        if($difference > 0){ echo "Nog ".$days_left." dagen ".$hours_left." uur               .$minutes_left." minuten  tot de dienst"; }
        else{ echo "De vorige dienst is afgelopen."; } 
    }
    ?> 
    </a>
</div>
```

So what i want is just the echo but then have all the php code not in my div but above the html code. like:

```
<?php ..... ?>
<html>
<body>
echo
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can quick-echo by storing a variable and using `<?= $var ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a php function or variable outside of a PHP block. However, it is possible to store a value in a php `variable` then use it in a tiny PHP block.

For example:

```
<?php
// ...
$foo = 42;
// ...
?>
```

Then

```
<html><body>
    <p>Answer is <?php echo $foo; ?></p>
</body></html>
```

or

```
<html><body>
    <p>Answer is <?= $foo; ?></p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pemeon said, *Smarty* is quite a smart (pun intended) approach for that.

If you want to learn more about the backgrounds, you might want to google for "**Model-View-Controller** in php" or something like that. Basically, it's about separating your view (all the presentation stuff, e.g. HTML) from your code logic (controller) and your data objects / sources (model).

*Smarty* is nice but you'll need a bit of learning time to figure out how the template engine is designed, how to use it and how to apply it to your specific challenges.

If you don't want such a big solution at the moment and want to start a bit smaller and easier, you could write your own very simple template "engine" around the functions `file_get_contents(...)` and `str_ireplace`. The idea looks like this: You put your HTML stuff in template-files (for example *.html or *.tpl file ending) that don't contain any php code but place holders for dynamically created content:

Example: *main-layout.tpl*

```
<html>
<head><title>${Title}</title></head>
<body>
<img src="yourfancylogo.png" alt="Header logo"><br>
<a href="#">Here some navigation</a> | <a href="#">...</a> | ... <br>
${Content}
<hr>
<div id="footer">&copy; 2013 John Doe - <a href="index.php?requestedpage=contact">Contact us</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: *welcome.tpl*

```
<h1>Hello, ${Username}! Nice to see you!</h1>
<p>So your username is ${Username}? Then you might want to read our terms of service before starting to use our app:</p>
<pre>${TOS}</pre>
```

Example: *tos-document.txt*

```
1) An apple a day keeps the doctor away!
2) No Smoking!
3) ...
```

In your php script you do something like this:

```
<?php

  $template = file_get_contents('main-layout.tpl');

  if (isset($_GET['requestedpage'])) {
    // Parameter given!
    $requestedPage = $_GET['requestedpage'];
  } else {
    // No page parameter. Assume "home".
    $requestedPage = "home";
  }

  $username = "Monty";   // get from session data

  if ($requestedPage == 'home') {
    // -- begin handler code for page "home" --
    $title = "Start Page - Welcome";
    $content = file_get_contents('welcome.tpl');
    $tos = file_get_contents('tos-document.txt');
    $content = str_ireplace('${TOS}', $tos, $content);
    // -- end handler code for page "home" --
  } else if ($requestedPage == 'aboutus') {
    ...
  } else {
    $title = "Page Not Found - Error";
    $content = file_get_contents('error404.tpl');
    $content = str_ireplace('${PageThatWasNotFound}', htmlentities($requestedPage), $content);
  }

  $output = str_ireplace('${Content}', $content, $template);
  $output = str_ireplace('${Title}', htmlentities($title), $output);
  $output = str_ireplace('${Username}', htmlentities($username), $output);

  die($output);

?>
```

Using such a separation of the template and the data to insert, you can later modify your layout / template without having to touch your php scripts. For example, if you want to modify your header or footer shown on all pages, you have a **single point of change** as you can modularly assemble your site from several template-bricks.

To keep the php source above readable, while your source is becoming larger, you can put all the handler codes into separated php files. You'd include them by `include` or `require` into your main source file.

But watch out: You have to escape all placeholder values that might come from user inputs - regardless, if you get them from a database or directly from `$_GET` or `$_POST` (-> XSS vulnerabilities). **All input is evil!**

Comment: allright, i get your point. only im using now an template html based and its like: <html> <body> include header, include nav, include page, include sidebar, include footer. </body> </html>

Answer (score 0):

You could put your php in a separate file, and then use `include` or `require`.

do_stuff.php:

```
<?php
  // some calculations
  echo "stuff";
?>
```

Then in your html...

index.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'do_stuff.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[About include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use some template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). If you do not have time to learn you can for now just write code at the top and when you want to use some calculations in i.e  you use .

```
<?php
    // calculations
    $foo = 'foo';
?>
<html>
<body>
<div><?=$foo?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when you start to use this kind of 'separation' (php code in the top of the file) and html at the bottom and you will use this shortcut version of the echo function, you will easily transform into using template system.

Answer (score 0):

The goal should not be keeping `php` away from `html` code, the goal should be keeping *business logic* from *presentation logic*. One of the ways to do this is utilising a Model-View-Controller layout, or you could use one of many other paradigms. The main point of this approach is making changing one part independent of the other: imagine creating a separate mobile or `json` front end, that does all the exact same logic, but outputs it completely differently. If the business logic and presentation logic are completely entangled, you will have a hard time, probably needing to both reproduce or blatantly copy code, as well as creating two different branches that need to be kept in-sync, making maintaining it a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I`m using right now this sort of frame, its sort of like the frame MrSnurb made, but then in HTML in stead of php. what do you think about this framework guys?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = "home";
}   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Younited - <?php echo $page; ?></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container ronden">  
    <?php 
        include "partials/header.php";
        include "partials/menu.php"; 
    ?>
<div class="content">   
    <?php
        if (file_exists("partials/pages/".$page.".php")) {
            include "partials/pages/".$page.".php";
        }   
        else{ echo "<p>De pagina <b>".$page."</b> bestaat niet.</p>"; 
        } 
        include "partials/sidebar.php"; 
    ?>  
</div>
</div>
    <?php
        include "partials/footer.php";  
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use some template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). To create template of your html code and push there varibles.

Comment: i dont prefer using external programs

Comment: did you write your own mail-server, web-server, OS ?

Comment: no, ofcource not but i do not like programs who help me design a website i can do i by my own.